# Rails server unexpected token parse error for JSON request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, unicode

I am sending this curl request to my rails server

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:3000/articles' -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @body
```

the contents of request body is this json object

```
{'article': {'content': [u'\u0639\u0645\u0627\u0646 \u2013 \u0623\u0639\u0644\u0646 \u0645\u062d\u0627\u0641\u0638 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0632\u064a \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0643\u062a\u0648\u0631 \u0632\u064a\u0627\u062f \u0641\u0631\u064a\u0632 \u0639\u0646 \u0627\u0637\u0644\u0627\u0642 \u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u063a\u0631\u0641\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0642\u0627\u0635 \u0627\u0644\u0622\u0644\u064a (ACH) \u0627\u0644\u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a \u064a\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0641\u0642 \u0645\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u064a\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f (ISO 20022)\u060c \u0648\u0628\u062f\u0623 \u062a\u0634\u063a\u064a\u0644\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0639\u0644\u064a \u0646\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0647\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0636\u064a.',
                     u'\n\u0648\u0642\u0627\u0644 \u0641\u0631\u064a\u0632 \u0641\u064a \u0628\u064a\u0627\u0646 \u0623\u0635\u062f\u0631\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0645\u0633 \u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u064a\u0639\u062f \u064a627\u0644\u0642\u0627\u0639\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0633\u0627\u0633\u064a\u0629 \u0644\u062a\u0642\u0627\u0635 \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0648\u0627\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0635\u063a\u064a\u0631\u0629 \u0648\u0645\u062a\u0648\u0633\u0637\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062d\u062c\u0645 \u0628\u0639\u0645\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0645\u062e\u062a\u0644\u0641\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u062f\u0646\u060c \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0645\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a \u064a\u0633\u0647\u0644 \u0639\u0645\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u062a\u0642\u0627\u0635 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0645\u0648\u0627\u0644 \u0628\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0648\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0645\u0644\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0645\u0644\u0643\u0629 \u0648\u064a\u0642\u0644\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0639\u062a\u0645\u0627\u062f \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0642\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0631\u0642\u064a \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0634\u064a\u0643\u0627\u062a \u0641\u064a \u0639\u0645\u0644\u064a\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639.',
                     u'\u0648\u0623\u0636\u0627\u0641 \u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u064a\u0639\u0645\u0644 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u062a\u0634\u062c\u064a\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0627\u0637\u0646\u064a\u0646 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0639\u062a\u0645\u0627\u062f \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0631\u0648\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0645\u0648\u0627\u0644\u060c \u0646\u0638\u0631\u0627 \u0644\u0633\u0631\u0639\u062a\u0647\u0627 \u0648\u0627\u0646\u062e\u0641\u0627\u0636 \u062a\u0643\u0644\u0641\u062a\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u0642\u0627\u0631\u0646\u0629 \u0628\u062a\u0643\u0644\u0641\u0629 \u0623\u062f\u0648\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062a\u0627\u062d\u0629 \u062d\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0627\u060c \u0628\u0645\u0627 \u064a\u0639\u0632\u0632 \u0627\u0644\u0643\u0641\u0627\u0621\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0642\u062a\u0635\u0627\u062f\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u062f\u0627\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u064a\u0648\u0644\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0629 \u0644\u062f\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0648\u0643\u060c \u0648\u062a\u0633\u0647\u064a\u0644 \u062f\u0648\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0642\u0648\u062f \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0642\u062a\u0635\u0627\u062f \u0628\u0637\u0631\u064a\u0642\u0629 \u0622\u0645\u0646\u0629 \u0648\u0641\u0639\u0627\u0644\u0629\u060c \u0645\u0627 \u064a\u062f\u0639\u0645 \u062a\u0646\u0641\u064a\u0630 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u064a\u0627\u0633\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0642\u062f\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u064a\u0633\u0627\u0647\u0645 \u0641\u064a \u062a\u062d\u0642\u064a\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0642\u0631\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0645\u0644\u0643\u0629.',
                     u'\n\u0648\u0627\u0648\u0636\u062d \u0623\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u062e\u062f\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u064a\u0627\u0631 (ISO 20022) \u0641\u064a \u0639\u0645\u0644\u064a\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644 \u0636\u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f \u0633\u064a\u0633\u0627\u0647\u0645 \u0641\u064a \u062a\u0633\u0647\u064a\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0639\u0627\u0645\u0644 \u0645\u0639 \u0623\u064a\u0629 \u062a\u0637\u0648\u0631\u0627\u062a \u0645\u0633\u062a\u0642\u0628\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0633\u0648\u0627\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0623\u0646\u0638\u0645\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0645\u0644\u0643\u0629\u060c \u0645\u0624\u0643\u062f\u0627 \u0623\u0647\u0645\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u062c\u0648\u062f \u0628\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u0645\u062a\u0643\u0627\u0645\u0644\u0629 \u0648\u0641\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0627\u064a\u064a\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0644\u0645\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0645\u0627\u0631\u0633\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0636\u0644\u0649\u060c \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u064a\u0648\u0641\u0631\u0647\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f \u0644\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0648\u0643 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u0633\u0633\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629\u060c \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a \u0633\u064a\u0633\u0627\u0647\u0645 \u0641\u064a \u062a\u0639\u0632\u064a\u0632 \u0645\u0635\u062f\u0627\u0642\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0628\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0648\u0643.',
                     u'\n\u0648\u0623\u0636\u0627\u0641 \u0641\u0631\u064a\u0632\u060c \u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0646\u0638\u0648\u0645\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f\u0629 \u0642\u0627\u062f\u0631\u0629 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0645\u0639\u0627\u0644\u062c\u0629 \u062a\u0642\u0627\u0635 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0627\u0626\u0646\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u064a\u0646\u0629 \u0628\u062c\u0645\u064a\u0639 \u0623\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0639\u0647\u0627\u060c \u0645\u0627 \u0633\u064a\u0648\u0641\u0631 \u062e\u064a\u0627\u0631\u0627\u062a \u0645\u062a\u0639\u062f\u062f\u0629 \u0644\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0648\u0643 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0641\u0631\u0627\u062f \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0643\u0627\u062a.',
                     u'\n\u0648\u064a\u0636\u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0648\u0627\u0641\u0642\u064a\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0636\u0645\u0646 \u0628\u064a\u0626\u0627\u062a \u0639\u0645\u0644 \u0645\u062e\u062a\u0644\u0641\u0629\u060c \u0628\u0645\u0627 \u064a\u062f\u0639\u0645 \u0627\u0628\u062a\u0643\u0627\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0646\u062a\u062c\u0627\u062a \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062e\u062f\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629\u060c \u0648\u064a\u0642\u062f\u0645 \u0641\u0648\u0627\u0626\u062f \u0648\u0627\u0636\u062d\u0629 \u0644\u0644\u0627\u0642\u062a\u0635\u0627\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u062f\u0646\u064a.',
                     u'\n\u0648\u0628\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0643\u062a\u0648\u0631 \u0641\u0631\u064a\u0632 \u0623\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0633\u064a\u062d\u0642\u0642 \u0648\u0641\u0648\u0631\u0627\u062a \u0643\u0628\u064a\u0631\u0629 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u0637\u0627\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0631\u0643\u0627\u062a \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u0633\u0633\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0643\u0648\u0645\u064a\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0625\u0631\u0633\u0627\u0644 \u0645\u0644\u0641\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0645\u062a\u0639\u062f\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0633\u062a\u0641\u064a\u062f\u064a\u0646 \u0645\u062b\u0644 \u0645\u0644\u0641\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0648\u0627\u062a\u0628\u060c \u0648\u0623\u0631\u0628\u0627\u062d \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0633\u0647\u0645\u060c \u0648\u0631\u0648\u0627\u062a\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0636\u0645\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u062c\u062a\u0645\u0627\u0639\u064a \u0648\u063a\u064a\u0631\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639\u0627\u062a\u060c \u0639\u0644\u0627\u0648\u0629 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u062a\u0641\u0627\u0648\u064a\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0642\u064a\u062f \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0633\u0627\u0628\u0627\u062a \u0644\u0644\u0648\u0641\u0627\u0621 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u062a\u0632\u0627\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062c\u062f\u0648\u0644\u0629 \u0628\u0622\u062c\u0627\u0644 \u0645\u062e\u062a\u0644\u0641\u0629 \u0628\u0633\u0647\u0648\u0644\u0629 \u0648\u064a\u0633\u0631 \u0648\u0636\u0645\u0646 \u0628\u064a\u0626\u0629 \u0622\u0645\u0646\u0629.',
                     u'\n\u0628\u062f\u0648\u0631\u0647\u060c \u0628\u064a\u0646 \u0645\u062f\u064a\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0634\u0631\u0648\u0639 \u0645\u0643\u0633\u064a\u0645 \u0628\u0648\u0631\u064a\u0633\u064a\u0646\u0643\u0648\u060c \u0645\u0646 \u0634\u0631\u0643\u0629\xa0 CMA\u060c \u0623\u0646 \u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u064a\u0648\u0641\u0631 \u0641\u0648\u0627\u0626\u062f \u0648\u0645\u0632\u0627\u064a\u0627 \u0625\u0636\u0627\u0641\u064a\u0629 \u0639\u0632\u0632\u062a \u0639\u0645\u0644\u064a\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644 \u0641\u064a \u0623\u0646\u0638\u0645\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u062f\u0646\u060c \u0648\u0645\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u062e\u0635\u0627\u0626\u0635 \u0645\u062a\u0627\u0628\u0639\u0629 \u0648\u0645\u0631\u0627\u0642\u0628\u0629 \u0645\u062a\u0645\u064a\u0632\u0629 \u0644\u0639\u0645\u0644\u064a\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0632\u064a \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0648\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062c\u0627\u0631\u064a\u0629\u060c \u0648\u0648\u0638\u0627\u0626\u0641 \u062e\u0627\u0635\u0629 \u0628\u0625\u062f\u0627\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u064a\u0648\u0644\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u062f\u0627\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062e\u0627\u0637\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0635\u0627\u062d\u0628\u0629 \u0644\u0647\u0627\u060c \u0648\u0628\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u062a\u062d\u062a\u064a\u0629 \u062a\u0645\u062a\u0627\u0632 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0631\u0639\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0641\u0639\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0645\u0627\u0646 \u0628\u0645\u0627 \u064a\u0633\u0647\u0644 \u0645\u0648\u0627\u0643\u0628\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0637\u0648\u0631\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0642\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0633\u0648\u0627\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629.',
                     u'\n\u064a\u0630\u0643\u0631 \u0623\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f \u064a\u062e\u062f\u0645 \u062c\u0645\u064a\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0648\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0645\u0644\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0645\u0644\u0643\u0629 \u0645\u0646 \u062e\u0644\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0628\u0643\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0622\u0645\u0646\u0629 \u0644\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0648\u0643 VPN \u0643\u0634\u0628\u0643\u0629 \u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633\u064a\u0629 \u0644\u062a\u0646\u0627\u0642\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629\u060c \u0643\u0645\u0627 \u064a\u0645\u0643\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u062e\u062f\u0627\u0645 \u0634\u0628\u0643\u0629 \u0633\u0648\u064a\u0641\u062a \u0628\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0648\u0643 \u0643\u0634\u0628\u0643\u0629 \u0628\u062f\u064a\u0644\u0629.',
                     u'\n\u0648\u0623\u0639\u0631\u0628 \u0641\u0631\u064a\u0632 \u0648\u0641\u0631\u064a\u0642 \u0645\u0634\u0631\u0648\u0639 \u062a\u0637\u0628\u064a\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0639\u0646 \u0634\u0643\u0631\u0647\u0645 \u0644\u0644\u0642\u0637\u0627\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0635\u0631\u0641\u064a \u0648\u0634\u0631\u0643\u0629 CMA \u0648\u062c\u0645\u0639\u064a\u0629 SWIFT \u0644\u062a\u0639\u0627\u0648\u0646\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062b\u0645\u0631 \u0641\u064a \u0625\u0646\u062c\u0627\u062d \u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0634\u0631\u0648\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0637\u0646\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0647\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0630\u064a \u062c\u0627\u0621 \u0644\u064a\u062a\u0645\u0645 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0631\u0627\u062a\u064a\u062c\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0632\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0631\u062f\u0646\u064a \u0644\u0644\u0623\u0639\u0648\u0627\u0645 2013-2016 \u0627\u0644\u0647\u0627\u062f\u0641\u0629 \u0625\u0644\u0649 \u0625\u0639\u0627\u062f\u0629 \u0647\u064a\u0643\u0644\u0629 \u0648\u062a\u0637\u0648\u064a\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u062a\u064a\u0629 \u0644\u0623\u0646\u0638\u0645\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0645\u0644\u0643\u0629 \u0627\u0646\u062a\u0642\u0627\u0644\u0627 \u0645\u0646 \u0628\u064a\u0626\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0631\u0642\u064a \u0625\u0644\u0649 \u0628\u064a\u0626\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0631\u0648\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u0644\u062e\u062f\u0645\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0627\u0637\u0646\u064a\u0646 \u0648\u0643\u0627\u0641\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0639\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0642\u062a\u0635\u0627\u062f\u064a\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0645\u0644\u0643\u0629.',
                     u'\n\u0648\u0630\u0643\u0631 \u0623\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0632\u064a \u0637\u0648\u0631 \u0641\u064a \u0639\u0627\u0645 2014 \u0628\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u062a\u062d\u062a\u064a\u0629 \u0645\u0646 \u062e\u0648\u0627\u062f\u0645 \u0648\u0634\u0628\u0643\u0627\u062a \u0628\u062a\u0643\u0646\u0648\u0644\u0648\u062c\u064a\u0627 \u062d\u062f\u064a\u062b\u0629 \u0648\u0645\u062a\u0637\u0648\u0631\u0629 \u062a\u062e\u062f\u0645 \u0623\u0646\u0638\u0645\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0631\u0648\u0646\u064a \u0645\u0646 \u062b\u0644\u0627\u062b\u0629 \u0645\u0648\u0627\u0642\u0639\u060c \u0631\u0626\u064a\u0633\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u062b\u0627\u0646\u0648\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0645\u0648\u0642\u0639 \u062a\u0639\u0627\u0641\u064a \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062e\u0627\u0637\u0631 \u0648\u0636\u0645\u0646 \u0623\u0643\u062b\u0631 \u0645\u0646 \u0634\u0628\u0643\u0629 \u0622\u0645\u0646\u0629 \u062a\u0631\u0628\u0637 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0632\u064a \u0645\u0639 \u0643\u0627\u0641\u0629 \u0628\u0646\u0648\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0645\u0644\u0643\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0627\u0642\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u062b\u0644\u0627\u062b\u0629.',
                     u'\n\u0648\u0643\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0632\u064a \u0623\u0637\u0644\u0642 \u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0639\u0631\u0636 \u0648\u062a\u062d\u0635\u064a\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0648\u0627\u062a\u064a\u0631 \u0625\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0631\u0648\u0646\u064a\u0627 -\u0625\u064a \u0641\u0648\u0627\u062a\u064a\u0631\u0643\u0645- \u0641\u064a \u0645\u0646\u062a\u0635\u0641 \u0639\u0627\u0645 2014\u060c \u062a\u0644\u0627\u0647 \u0625\u0637\u0644\u0627\u0642 \u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0633\u0648\u064a\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0625\u062c\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0641\u0648\u0631\u064a RTGS \u0628\u0623\u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0627\u0635\u0641\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0644\u0645\u064a\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0628\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0648\u0644 \u0645\u0646 \u0639\u0627\u0645 2015\u060c \u0628\u0627\u0644\u062a\u0632\u0627\u0645\u0646 \u0645\u0639 \u0625\u0637\u0644\u0627\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0644\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0648\u0644\u0649 \u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062e\u062f\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0635\u0631\u0641\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0631\u0648\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u0644\u0639\u0645\u0644\u0627\u0621 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0632\u064a \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u0633\u0633\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0643\u0648\u0645\u064a\u0629 e-banking\u060c \u062b\u0645 \u0625\u0637\u0644\u0627\u0642 \u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0641\u0639 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0647\u0627\u062a\u0641 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0642\u0627\u0644 JoMoPay.',
                     u'\n\u0648\u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0631\u0628\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0648\u0644 \u0645\u0646 \u0639\u0627\u0645 2016\u060c \u062a\u0645 \u0625\u0637\u0644\u0627\u0642 \u0627\u0644\u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0624\u062a\u0645\u062a \u0644\u0625\u062f\u0627\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062d\u0644\u064a\u060c \u0648\u0645\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u0625\u062f\u0627\u0631\u0629 \u0645\u0632\u0627\u062f\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0646\u062f\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0643\u0648\u0645\u064a\u0629\u060c \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062a\u062f\u0627\u0648\u0644 \u0628\u0627\u0644\u0633\u0646\u062f\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u062d\u0643\u0648\u0645\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u062e\u062f\u0645\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u064a\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0627\u0645\u060c \u0648\u0633\u0646\u062f\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0641\u0631\u0627\u062f Depo/X .',
                     u'\n\u0648\u0641\u064a \u0633\u064a\u0627\u0642 \u0645\u062a\u0635\u0644\u060c \u0639\u0642\u062f\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0644\u062c\u0646\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0648\u062c\u064a\u0647\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0644\u064a\u0627 \u0644\u062a\u0642\u0646\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0639\u0644\u0648\u0645\u0627\u062a \u0641\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0632\u064a \u0628\u0631\u0626\u0627\u0633\u0629 \u0641\u0631\u064a\u0632 \u0648\u0646\u0627\u0626\u0628\u064a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062d\u0627\u0641\u0638\u060c \u0648\u0645\u062f\u0631\u0627\u0621 \u062f\u0648\u0627\u0626\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0632\u064a \u0627\u062c\u062a\u0645\u0627\u0639\u0627 \u0644\u0645\u0646\u0627\u0642\u0634\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0634\u0631\u0648\u0639\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0637\u0631\u0648\u062d\u0629 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u062e\u0637\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0631\u0627\u062a\u064a\u062c\u064a\u0629 \u0644\u0644\u0641\u062a\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0642\u0628\u0644\u0629 \u0644\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0643\u0645\u0627\u0644 \u0645\u0633\u064a\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0637\u0648\u064a\u0631 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0623\u062a\u0645\u062a\u0629 \u0644\u0644\u0623\u0639\u0645\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0635\u0631\u0641\u064a\u0629\u060c \u0648\u0633\u064a\u0639\u0644\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0646\u0643 \u0639\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0631\u0627\u062a\u064a\u062c\u064a\u062a\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0642\u0628\u0644\u0629 \u0641\u064a \u062d\u064a\u0646\u0647 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0634\u0627\u0648\u0631 \u062d\u0648\u0644\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u0639 \u0634\u0631\u0643\u0627\u0626\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0627\u0633\u062a\u0631\u0627\u062a\u064a\u062c\u064a\u064a\u0646. (\u0628\u062a\u0631\u0627)'],
         'headline': [u'\xab\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0643\u0632\u064a\xbb \u064a\u0637\u0644\u0642 \u0646\u0638\u0627\u0645\u0627 \u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f\u0627 \u0644\u0644\u062a\u062d\u0648\u064a\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0631\u0648\u0646\u064a \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062a\u0642\u0627\u0635']}}
```

And this is my articles controller which i simply generated through scaffolding

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end


  def edit
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:headline, :content, :location, :date)
    end
end
```

and here's the model

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :headline, type: String
  field :content, type: String
  field :location, type: String
  field :date, type: DateTime
end
```

The rails server says "Error occurred while parsing request parameters" and displays this error `ActionDispatch::ParamsParser::ParseError (822: unexpected token at '{'article': {'content': [u'\u0639\u064.....` so what is the issue here.

I don't know if this could be of importance, but i'm getting my data through scraping Arabic newspaper articles, i noticed that all my requests to create them through the rails server were failing and so tried out a single curl request to see what the issue could be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data:

```
{'article': {'content':  ...
```

isn't JSON. JSON object property names are strings and [strings in JSON use double quotes](http://json.org):

> A *string* is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.

You need to fix your data so that it really is JSON.

The `u` prefixes on your single-quoted "strings" will also be a problem, that's not JSON either.